# TYPO3 12.1.3 - getting 503 code after attempt login by LoginForm on frontend

Tags: mariadb, typo3

Backend works correct. Problem is only on frontend with additionally Login Form on custom login site.
I getting 503 error after trying login by "Login Panel". It doesn't matter right or wrong login data.

[image: 1]

I turned off the redirect on backend but I still get this same error with log below:

Core: Exception handler (WEB): Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: #1064: An exception occurred while executing a query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ')))) AND (`fe_users`.`deleted` = 0)' at line 1 | Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException thrown in file /public/my_site_name/vendor/doctrine/dbal/src/Driver/API/MySQL/ExceptionConverter.php in line 86. Requested URL: https://my-domain-name.pl/login?tx_felogin_login%5Baction%5D=login&tx_felogin_login%5Bcontroller%5D=Login&cHash=9238b3d3ba4dbeb2c75d778a5cd1f17b

I know it is probably cause by third party extension like bootstrap (bk2k). But I don't believe I need to rewrite manual syntax in my mariadb. it's ridiculous.

Im checked requirements for this version of TYPO3. And my requirements are ok. Im checked my database (MariaDB) by mysqlcheck and all is ok. Checked version of MariaDB and its ok.

Im beginner in TYPO3 so please be understanding.

Comment: which TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: See title - 12.1.3

Comment: Do you have any custom extensions that extend the felogin extension? It seems there is a SQL syntax error in there.

Comment: "typo3/cms-base-distribution": "^12.1",
"bk2k/bootstrap-package": "^13.0",
"typo3/cms-viewpage": "^12.1",
"typo3/cms-seo": "^12.1",
"typo3/cms-setup": "^12.1",
"typo3/cms-reports": "^12.1"

Comment: I deleted all (files and database) and make a new install by composer. This time only "typo3/cms-base-distribution": "^12.1", "bk2k/bootstrap-package": "^13.0". This same result...

Comment: I am not using currently the bootstrap package. can you please test once without the package and plain core?
12 is not yet a LTS and might still include bugs - I would be more than happy to fix it once reproduceable without any extension

Comment: I am using the bootstrap package in Drupal and now in TYPO3. I install the typo3/cms-base-distribution ver.11.5.22 and currently bk2k/bootstrap-package. Now all is ok. The latest version of TYPO3 not working correctly with latest bootstrap package indeed.

Answer (score 0):

```
root@database-deb:/home/marlon# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.7.3-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline EditLine wrapper
```

I looked in wrong places. On TYPO3 site you can see:

> System requirements PHP 8.1 MariaDB 10.3+ / MySQL 8.0+ / PostgreSQL
> 10.0+ / SQLite 3.8.3+

but if you see details:
[Requirements on TYPO3 site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTvZX.png)

MariaDB >= 10.3.0 <= 10.6.99 **is not the same** MariaDB 10.3+

I guess, due to incompatible version of mariadb...

A few hours later... I create new one VM with older MariaDB.

```
root@mariadb-10-6:/home/marlon# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.11-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline EditLine wrapper
```

Nothing changed. Still same error.

Comment: Using the previous version (11.5.22) of TYPO3 is the solution on this time for me. MariaDB 10.6.11.